# How to obtain a google-services.json file for Android app from Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: android, google-signin

I've been trying to get started on an Android app with Google Sign in as a principal feature, and one of the steps I've encountered in the process of getting the integration working is creating a `google-services.json` file in the `./app` directory, [which can apparently somehow be downloaded](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured=true). Google's docs are wholly incomplete, especially for a newbie Android, so I've been learning from [a tutorial I found from about a year ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PIaGpJMCNs).

I haven't figured out how to get a `google-services.json` file, especially because the prerequisite page that the above docs link refers to for downloading a `google-services.json` file instead helps me obtain a `credentials.json` file. Are these the same thing? Do they work the same way? Is `credentials.json` the new version of `google-services.json`? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link your app to Firebase Console. After linking you will get google-services.json file. You can easily download from the firebase console.
Visit https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: But what does Firebase have to do with Google Sign In? I'm not using the Firebase database in my project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use credential.js instead of google-service.json file. Google signing will work fluently. And yeah you can say its upgraded version but if you want google-service.json file you must link your account with Firebase